# Should boolean features be normalized and should false be -1 or 0

Tags: feature-selection, normalization

I am attempting to train an SVM from a set of features which are both numeric and categorical, for example:

- Distance X (Numeric)
- Distance Y (Numeric)
- Font Size Difference (Numeric)
- Word 1 Bold (Boolean)
- Word 2 Bold (Boolean)
- Word 1 Font Size (Numeric)
- ...

For mapping the features to a feature array I am treating true as 1 and false as 0 and then normalizing the entire feature array using Z-Scores.

Should I instead encode false as -1 so it has a numerical impact on the generation of the support vectors, with a value of 0 it does not modify the chosen vector (I assume)?

Should boolean features be normalized in the same way as numerics or should they be left with their encoded values?

Comment: You can always try a couple different configurations and see what does best on your held out validation set

Comment: The value, whether it is -1, 0, 50, -50, does not matter for SVM. Normalization is not needed, unless the underlying SVM estimator uses gradient descent, which is atypical.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment by Ricardo Cruz I tried switching the value of false from 0 to -1 and also normalization on and off.

Neither switching the value from 0 to - 1 or normalization of features had any impact on the values predicted by the SVM. In this case I was using a Gaussian kernel and Sequential Minimal Optimization for my SVM.